# aws cloudformation CachePolicy generic error

Tags: caching, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudfront

i'm trying to create a cachePolicy that forward all ( cookies, querystrings and headers ) and acctualy **doesn't cache** annything at all:

```
    Type: AWS::CloudFront::CachePolicy
    Properties:
      CachePolicyConfig:
        Comment: Cache Policy
        DefaultTTL: 0
        MaxTTL: 0
        MinTTL: 0
        Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-cache-policy
        ParametersInCacheKeyAndForwardedToOrigin:
          CookiesConfig:
            CookieBehavior: all
          EnableAcceptEncodingBrotli: true
          EnableAcceptEncodingGzip: true
          HeadersConfig:
            HeaderBehavior: whitelist
            Headers: 
              - "*"
          QueryStringsConfig:
            QueryStringBehavior: all
```

and my OriginRequestPolicy:

```
OriginRequestPolicy:
    Type: AWS::CloudFront::OriginRequestPolicy
    Properties:
      OriginRequestPolicyConfig:
        Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-origin-request
        CookiesConfig:
          CookieBehavior: all
        HeadersConfig:
          HeaderBehavior: allViewer
        QueryStringsConfig:
          QueryStringBehavior: all
```

but whem i try to upload the stack, i get a generic error:

```
The following resource(s) failed to create: [OriginRequestPolicy, CachePolicy]. Rollback requested by user. OriginRequestPolicy CREATE_FAILED   Resource creation cancelled CachePolicy CREATE_FAILED   Invalid request provided: AWS::CloudFront::CachePolicy
```

what am i missing?

obs: I can't only create an `AWS::CloudFront::OriginRequestPolicy` cause it's seems that i can only have a OriginRequestPolicy if alredy exists a cacheRequestPolicy first..

Comment: I can't see your entire scenario, but you must have a cache policy in order to specify an origin request policy.

"To use an origin request policy, the cache behavior must also use a cache policy. You cannot use an origin request policy in a cache behavior without a cache policy."

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/controlling-origin-requests.html

Comment: thanks for your comment. actually, it was already pointed on my observation, but i ended up using the pre-made policies: they perfectly satisfied  my needs

Comment: For me the issue was space in the cache policy name. Once I replaced space with a dash, the generic error was gone. I cant see your complete name here tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error seems to be caused by the name property. For me, having a '.' in the name produces the error.

Nothing is stated regarding this in the documentation unfortunately:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cloudfront-cachepolicy-cachepolicyconfig.html#cfn-cloudfront-cachepolicy-cachepolicyconfig-name

This works:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09

Resources:
  CachePolicy:
    Type: AWS::CloudFront::CachePolicy
    Properties:
      CachePolicyConfig:
        DefaultTTL: 1
        MaxTTL: 1
        MinTTL: 1
        Name: test
        ParametersInCacheKeyAndForwardedToOrigin:
          CookiesConfig:
            CookieBehavior: all
          EnableAcceptEncodingBrotli: false
          EnableAcceptEncodingGzip: false
          HeadersConfig:
            HeaderBehavior: none
          QueryStringsConfig:
            QueryStringBehavior: all
```

Hyphen in the name works:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09

Resources:
  CachePolicy:
    Type: AWS::CloudFront::CachePolicy
    Properties:
      CachePolicyConfig:
        DefaultTTL: 1
        MaxTTL: 1
        MinTTL: 1
        Name: test-id
        ParametersInCacheKeyAndForwardedToOrigin:
          CookiesConfig:
            CookieBehavior: all
          EnableAcceptEncodingBrotli: false
          EnableAcceptEncodingGzip: false
          HeadersConfig:
            HeaderBehavior: none
          QueryStringsConfig:
            QueryStringBehavior: all
```

Does not work:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09

Resources:
  CachePolicy:
    Type: AWS::CloudFront::CachePolicy
    Properties:
      CachePolicyConfig:
        DefaultTTL: 1
        MaxTTL: 1
        MinTTL: 1
        Name: test-id.test
        ParametersInCacheKeyAndForwardedToOrigin:
          CookiesConfig:
            CookieBehavior: all
          EnableAcceptEncodingBrotli: false
          EnableAcceptEncodingGzip: false
          HeadersConfig:
            HeaderBehavior: none
          QueryStringsConfig:
            QueryStringBehavior: all
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why the "manual way" doesn't work, but i found from the documentation 2 pre-made policies that satisfy my needs:

```
Name: Managed-CachingDisabled
ID: 4135ea2d-6df8-44a3-9df3-4b5a84be39ad
This policy disables caching. This policy is useful for dynamic content and for requests that are not cacheable.
```

and

```
Name: Managed-AllViewer
ID: 216adef6-5c7f-47e4-b989-5492eafa07d3
This policy includes all values (query strings, headers, and cookies) in the viewer request.
```

doc reference:

https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-managed-cache-policies.html

https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-managed-origin-request-policies.html